# PHP loop to make MYSQL Queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of IDs generated from a set of checkboxes as follows:

```
$list = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['checkbox']));
```

which outputs a list like this:

a,b,c

I want to set a column in a MYSQL database that corresponds to each list item, I am unsuccessfully trying to create a query with a foreach loop like so:

```
$update_query= '';
foreach($list as $item){     //error on this line
 $update_query .= "
  INSERT INTO t (Col_1, Col_2)
  VALUES  ('".$item."',now());
     ";}
```

It fails telling me I have supplied an invalid argument for foreach(), but I'm not sure, a. what that means, and b. how to fix it; can anyone offer any guidance to get my loop working or a better way of doing this INSERT.

Thanks

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/foreach http://php.net/implode

Comment: I do check the php manual before I post here, but as I'm self taught with ~3months knowledge I often find them difficult to understand.  Regardless, thanks for taking the time to read my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$list` is a string, not an array. Try passing in the array before you have imploaded it:

```
$update_query= '';

foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $item)
{
    $update_query .= "INSERT INTO t (Col_1, Col_2) VALUES ('".addslashes($item)."', now());"; 
}
```

You'd be much better off using prepared statements, though!

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much.  Could you give me an example of how to use a prepared statement in this case?